# Does API of TestCafe setFileUpload have auto convert content type of File

Tags: javascript, file-upload, automation, testcafe

I'm using testcafe for creating automation test script and have test scenarios related to upload file.
I have create function to upload file
     `async setFileToUpload(filePath) { await t.setFilesToUpload("#file-input", filePath); }`

But have problem i have a file and i can upload it normally in my web, but when use function setFileUpload to upload the file, the page is have error message related to format and content type of file

Have anyone know the issue and how to resolved it

Comment: Please share a simple sample that we can run locally.